# How to make recyclerview items overlap image slider

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i have an image slider and a recyclerview which contains news.

When scrolling recyclerview from bottom to top the recyclerview is going (hiding) under the image slider as this picture shows from my app i am currently developing:

[image]

And this a screenshot from a news app on my device :

[image]

As you can see in the last picture how the recyclerview is overlapping the image slider.

How can i achieve that ?

This my fragment xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/framelayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearFragmentOne"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <com.baoyz.widget.PullRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:refreshColors="@array/colors_swipe"
            app:refreshType="ring"
            android:layout_height="200dp">

            <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
                android:id="@+id/slider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                custom:indicator_visibility="visible"
                custom:pager_animation="Accordion"
                custom:pager_animation_span="1100" />

        </com.baoyz.widget.PullRefreshLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_marquee"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:singleLine="true"
            />

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"

            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_post"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                />

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

i have UPDATED the fragment xml as this one :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/framelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        <com.baoyz.widget.PullRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:refreshColors="@array/colors_swipe"
            app:refreshType="ring"
            android:layout_height="200dp">

            <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
                android:id="@+id/slider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                custom:indicator_visibility="visible"
                custom:pager_animation="Accordion"
                custom:pager_animation_span="1100" />

        </com.baoyz.widget.PullRefreshLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_marquee"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:singleLine="true"
            />

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"

            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_post"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:behavior_overlapTop="100dp"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                />

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Nothing changed just a simple toolbar was added in the top of the imageslider

FINAL_UPDATE :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/framelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.baoyz.widget.PullRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:refreshColors="@array/colors_swipe"
            app:refreshType="ring"
            android:layout_height="200dp">

            <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
                android:id="@+id/slider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                custom:indicator_visibility="visible"
                custom:pager_animation="Accordion"
                custom:pager_animation_span="1100" />

        </com.baoyz.widget.PullRefreshLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_marquee"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:singleLine="true"
            />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_post"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDK what your PullRefreshLayout widget does but you can get the behaviour you want by adding an AppBarLayout with the Slider inside and the PullRefreshLayout if necessary. And then add `app:behavior_overlapTop="here goes the amount of dp you want to overlap over the AppBarLayout"`on the NestedScrollView and/or the RecyclerView.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
            android:id="@+id/slider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            custom:indicator_visibility="visible"
            custom:pager_animation="Accordion"
            custom:pager_animation_span="1100" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

...

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"

    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_post"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="100dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

This way you can adjust the amount the RecyclerView overlaps the AppBarLayout. If you need to this programmatically check [setOverlayTop](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior.html#setOverlayTop(int)).

But if you need to pass over completely, just wrap everything into the NestedScrollView and add the `app:layout_behavior` to the slider too so it goes up too when you scroll the RecyclerView, it won't overlap it, but it will take its space as the Slider goes upwards.

And if you want to do a custom overlapping, it would be handy to have the link to the libraries you used for the custom controls `com.baoyz.widget.PullRefreshLayout` and `com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout`.

**Update**

To clarify:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/framelayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/framelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
            <com.baoyz.widget.PullRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:refreshColors="@array/colors_swipe"
                app:refreshType="ring"
                android:layout_height="200dp">

                <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
                    android:id="@+id/slider"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    custom:indicator_visibility="visible"
                    custom:pager_animation="Accordion"
                    custom:pager_animation_span="1100" />

            </com.baoyz.widget.PullRefreshLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_marquee"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:singleLine="true"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_post"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:behavior_overlapTop="100dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help i have added my new xml fragment in the question.

The toolbar has been added in the top of the imageslider but still recyclerview is going under the imageslider

Comment: AppBarLayout is a wrapper for the toolbar and must be (if exists) the first element of a CoordinatorLayout. There I've updated the answer, could not test it because of the lack of the controls but I think it should work and, if it doesn't, add the behaviors to the NestedScrollView too.

Comment: i have updated my final xml .
I have wrapped everything into NestedScrollView and it seems very close what i wanted to do.

But there s one more thing how can i remove from the pullrefreshlayout from the nestedscrollview because i am not able to refresh

Comment: try moving the PullRefreshLayout outwards to wrap the NestedScrollView so you can refresh everything

Comment: Thanks a lot @fmaccaroni i get about 80% of what i really want .

I appreciate your help.